# Can two different people own a patent in different countries?

Tags: patentability, patent-applications

Lets say two people work on an idea or product. Then they decide to go their separate ways since they are both moving to different countries, but agree to patent the invention in the respective countries they are moving to. Is this allowed?

Answer (score 2):

Better course -and legally required in the US- is to file both applications as co-inventors and then used assignment to reach the desired ownership.